# Gebrauch von »worden« statt »geworden«

Tags: verb, history, grammar-identification

Ich unterrichte Deutsch als Fremdsprache für Philosophen und bin kein Deutschmuttersprachler. Ich bin neuerlich auf einen Gebrauch von *worden* gestoßen, den ich mehrmals gelesen habe aber worüber ich nie nachgedacht habe:

> die *allermeisten* finden es nicht verächtlich, dies oder jenes zu glauben und darnach zu leben, *ohne* sich vorher der letzten und sichersten Gründe für und wider bewusst **worden** zu sein.
>   *([Nietzsche, Die fröhliche Wissenschaft 1§2](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Nietzsche,+Friedrich/Die+fr%C3%B6hliche+Wissenschaft/Erstes+Buch/2.+Das+intellektuale+Gewissen))*

Die Bedeutung des Nebensatzes mit *worden* ist mir klar, die grammatische Erklärung dafür aber nicht. Hier hätte ich *geworden* erwartet, statt *worden,* denn *worden* kenne ich nur als Hilfsverb im Passiv.

Oder, hat das etwas mit dem Wort *bewusst* zu tun?

Wie lässt sich das am besten erklären?

Answer (score 2):

*werden* hat zwei verschiedene Formen des Partizip Perfekt (Partizip II): *geworden* und *worden*. Wie schon angemerkt wurde, wird *worden* als Partizip nur im Passiv verwendet.  Dies schreibt auch die David Vogt im Kommentar verlinkte [Sütterlin-Grammatik](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11023591_00309.html?zoom=1.0). Das [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/worden) schreibt etwas vager, dass die Hauptaussage im flektierten Verb ist, wenn *worden* verwendet wird.

Beispiele dafür sind:

> Ich bin angefahren **worden**.
>
> Das Essen ist aufgegessen **worden**.
>
> Der Knabe ist beschnitten **worden**.
>
> Sie war verwundet **worden**.

In allen diesen Fällen wäre die Verwendung des Partizips *geworden* ungrammatisch. In aktivischen Konstruktionen muss hingegen *geworden* verwendet werden:

> Wir sind über Nacht reich **geworden**.
>
> Ich bin erst im Alter so richtig glücklich und zufrieden **geworden**.

Hier wäre die Verwendung von *worden* falsch.

Im zitierten Beispiel aus dem Nietzsche-Text ist sicher strittig, ob es sich um eine Passivkonstruktion handelt. Möglicherweise will Nietzsche gerade ausdrücken, dass er den Akt der Bewusstseinswerdung als passiven Vorgang versteht. Möglicherweise war dies auch das zu seiner Zeit vorherrschende Konzept. Diese Frage zu beantworten würde eine Analyse des Kontexts, also des gesamten Textes und vielleicht auch des philosophischen Gesamtwerks Nietzsches erfordern, die den Rahmen dieses Forums sprengen würde.

Generell gibt es analoge Konstruktionen mit einigen Verben, in denen die Verwendung von *worden* nicht mehr üblich ist, früher aber üblich war. Mir ist nicht klar, ob das daran liegt, dass diese Verben früher als passiv aufgefasst wurden, oder ob sich die heute zu diagnostizierende Regel, dass *worden* nur in Passiv-Konstruktionen das Partizip Perfekt *geworden* ersetzt, erst später etabliert bzw. durchgesetzt hat.

Ein Beispiel hierfür ist *inne werden*:

> Ich bin mir meiner selbst inne worden. / Ich bin mir meiner selbst inne geworden.

Answer (score 2):

Nach kurzem Suchen im Text bin ich zu dem Schluß gelangt, daß Nietzsche die Formen so gebraucht, wie sie heute gebraucht werden: *worden* ist das Passivhilfsverb, *geworden* ist die Kopula.

Das *worden* für die Kopula im genannten Satz ist also sogar in Nietzsches eigener Sprache eine Ausnahme. In [Sütterlins Grammatik](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11023591_00309.html?zoom=1.0), die 1907 veröffentlicht wurde, gilt *geworden* als normal.

Und ein anderes mal schreibt Nietzsche sogar *bewusst geworden* (unten fett markiert).

> **Passiv**
>
> - was überhaupt bisher philosophirt worden ist
> - Aber bei alle diesem corrigirenden Lachen ist [...] die menschliche Natur verändert worden.
> - dass damit eine allzuschnelle Ausbildung desselben verhindert worden ist
> - dass diese wilde Habsucht und Ungerechtigkeit der Geschlechtsliebe dermaassen verherrlicht und vergöttlicht worden ist
> - dass durch diese Richtschnur alles Gewöhnte, Nächste und Unentbehrliche [...] unbillig beurtheilt und im Ganzen verleumdet worden ist
> - und Manches ist durch ihn überhaupt der Kunst hinzugefügt worden
> - Ein Instinct war in ihm stärker, als seine Weisheit, und war nie befriedigt worden
> - auf welche gewirkt worden ist
> - was von seinen Vorgängern als ein Schatz des Höchsten und Besten allmählich aufgehäuft worden ist
>
> **Kopula**
>
> - dass Einer damit nothwendig zum Düsterling geworden sei
> - wie unsrem Geschmacke der ganze romantische Aufruhr und Sinnen-Wirrwarr [...] fremd geworden ist
> - einstweilen ist die Komödie des Daseins sich selber noch nicht **„bewusst geworden“**
> - dass auf die Dauer über jeden Einzelnen dieser grossen Zwecklehrer bisher das Lachen und die Vernunft und die Natur Herr geworden ist
> - Der Mensch ist allmählich zu einem phantastischen Thiere geworden
> - es ist inzwischen stark und reif geworden
> - wenn sie Gewohnheit, Trieb und Leidenschaft geworden ist
> - dass jene alte Volks-Energie und Volks-Leidenschaft [...] nur weniger sichtbar geworden ist
> - Jetzt erst ist er [...] ein misstrauisches Thier geworden

Comment: +1 für die Recherche der Verwendung bei Nietzsche. Gute Idee und gut umgesetzt. Hervorragend!

Comment: Interessant ist doch aber, dass gerade das *bewusst geworden* in Anführungszeichen steht. Wen zitiert NIetzsche hier, oder worauf bezieht er sich? Drückt die Verwendung der Anführungszeichen vielleicht gerade eine Ironie gegenüber dieser Form aus?

Comment: Das Gegenüber der zwei Formen, einmal mit und einmal ohne Anführungszeichen, ist schon lustig. Meine Vermutung wäre aber, daß die Anführungszeichen daher rühren, daß das Subjekt keine Person ist bzw. eine Komödie kein Bewußtsein hat. Sie sollen also übertragenen Gebrauch anzeigen. Das ist aber nur eine Vermutung!

Answer (score 0):

Das ist richtig! Eigentlich müsste es *geworden* heißen.

*Wurden* und *worden* sind sehr verschiedene Formen:

- *Wurden* ist eine Personalform,
- *Worden* ist ein Partizip.
- *Wurden* ist 1. + 3. Person Plural Mitvergangenheit/Präteritum/Imperfekt von *werden*:

  > Mir wurde bewusst ...
- *Worden* und *geworden* sind beide das 2. Mittelwort / 2. Partizip / Partizip des Perfekts von *werden – wurde – (ge)worden,* werden aber verschieden verwendet.

  *Worden* wird nur bei einer Passivbildung im Perfekt verwendet und steht nach einem anderen 2. Partizip:

  > Die Bücher sind nicht mehr geliefert worden.

  Aber *geworden* wird verwendet als 2. Partizip des Vollverbs *werden:*

  > **Den Politikern ist endlich bewusst geworden, dass es so nicht weitergeht – und das schleckt keine Geiss weg!**
  >
  > Ihr seid  auch nicht jünger geworden.

Andere Verwendungen (»Er ist krank worden«) sind umgangssprachlich.

**Aber Nietzsche und ich schreiben halt eben so wie uns der Schnabel gewachsen {worden} ist.**

Comment: Die Behauptung »eigentlich müsste es *geworden* heissen« stimmt so nicht. Richtiger wäre »**heute** müsste es *geworden* heissen«. Der Text ist rund 150 Jahre alt, und damals, vor 150 Jahren, war der Satz völlig korrekt. Es hat sich nur in der Zwischenzeit das Regelwerk geändert.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Naja... Der Satz ist auch heute noch korrekt.

Comment: Man kann also eigentlich sagen: *worden* lässt sich grammatisch als Partizip Perfekt Passiv von *werden* auffassen. Es gibt das PPP sonst im Deutschen nicht, aber *werden* scheint hier eine Ausnahme zu bilden. Oder liege ich da falsch?

Comment: Laut [Sütterlins Grammatik](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11023591_00309.html?zoom=1.0) war *worden* als Partizip II der Kopula *werden* auch damals schon altmodisch (oder Dialekt).